# GNU GRUB black screen on boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a Windows 8.1/Ubuntu 12.04 dual boot, and it has been working just fine in the past.

I was working with Windows 8.1 today and chose Restart after being done and it took me to a black screen which shows this :

```
GNU GRUB Version 2.00-7 Ubuntu 11

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. 
For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. 
Anywhere else TAB lists the possible completions of a device/filename1 
grub>
```

If I press Tab it shows:

> Possible commands are; blocklist boot cat chainloader cmp color configfile debug displaymem embed find fstest geometry halt help hide impsprobe initrd install ioprobe kernel lock makeactive map md5crypt module modulenounzip pager partnew parttype password pause read reboot root rootnoverify savedefault serial setkey setup terminal terminfo testload testvbe unhide uppermem uuid vbeprobe grub>

I have tried solutions available all over the web and none seem to be working.
Constraints are:

1. I don't have a Windows installation disk because it came preinstalled with my laptop.
2. I'm using the HP ENVY 15-TouchSmart 64-bit.
3. I cannot boot into Windows since I'm stuck on the black screen with no options other than the ones above.
4. I had installed Ubuntu a week back using a pendrive and kept the partition settings default. So now I don't really know where exactly it got installed.
5. I am now booted into Ubuntu using the pendrive (that's now I am posting this question). So I can see the file system via the file folders, but I'm not able to understand what commands to execute now to solve the problem.

Secure boot is already set to off and my system was working perfectly fine until today some hours ago.

Comment: Nicely bumped.  There's a good chance that the OP has been waiting over 3 years for someone to help them boot their system.

Answer (score 1):

Try `boot-repair` by booting into Ubuntu from live USB. (I think you are already here)

#### Install boot repair

For this, open a terminal and do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

#### Run boot-repair

```
sudo boot-repair
```

Click on `Recommended repair`. Write on a paper the new URL that will appear.

Reboot your PC.

Comment: I did that and on reboot, it loaded windows 8 directly without the prompt asking for Ubuntu. So i restarted pressing shift and entered a menu which had boot Ubuntu (EFI) but on clicking that it again took me to the black screen. I can access windows now but Ubuntu seems dead. I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Follow the troubleshoooting given at the following link:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting